# 64 bit weblogic 32 bit oracle DB

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic11g, ora-01017

I have 64 bit Weblogic 11g installed on 64 bit Linux and trying to connect to a DB by creating a JDBC data source for Oracle 10g on 32 bit. I have connected another Weblogic 32 bit successfully to this DB instance.

However, for the 64 bit Weblogic I am getting exception

```
Connection test failed.
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied      
    oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:406)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:799)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:368)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:2
```

I am wondering does it need 64 bit Oracle database as well? My username and password are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Realise this is rather old, but sitll...

It shouldn't make any difference if the client and server are different versions. You are getting a connection, otherwise you'd see something more fatal than an ORA-01017. I'm wondering if the JDBC config was copied from the 32-bit WebLogic instance, and you're assuming that because it works there the config doesn't need to be changed. If that is the case, the encrypted password will be wrong; the encryption key is linked to the installation, so you can't just copy the file without updating it. Try running `java weblogic.security.Encrypt <password>` with the value you think it should be using, and see if that matches the 3DES value stored in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

No, the database doesn't need to be 64 bit. As @Alex mentioned, you are successfully talking to the db, this is just a credentials problem. Can you try to update the user and password of your connection pool (especially if you copied files under `domain\config\jdbc` from one domain to the other)?

Answer (score 1):

This is an Oracle error thrown when the user with which you are trying to access is not getting authenticated successfully in Oracle. Try to reset the user and password which you are trying or use a different user which is connecting fine and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the 64 bit version of Java installed and running on your Weblogic application server as well as the 64 bit Oracle client?